# Multiple POST requests, second request gets a 404 error code

Tags: python-3.x, request, python-requests, http-status-code-404

I am new to python and am having this same issue that was brought up as an issue on the requests GitHub. I am trying to authenticate to a website that redirects you to a security question after the initial login. Both the initial login and subsequent page use the same "action URL" and on the second post request I am receiving a 404, here is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated, after asking the question on GitHub they said it was a question to ask here as it wasn't on their end. (although they had an issue on their GitHub about this):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import time
sources = ["https://www.dandh.com/v4/view?pageReq=dhMainNS"]
req = requests.Session()


def login():
    authentication_url = "https://www.dandh.com/v4/dh"

    header = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:60.0)      Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"}

    payload = {"Login": "12345",
           "PW": "12345",
           "Request": "Login"}

    payload2 = {"securityAnswer": "12345",
            "Request": "postForm"}

    req.post(authentication_url, data=payload, headers=header)

    time.sleep(3)

    req.post(authentication_url, data=payload2, headers=header)

    time.sleep(3)


def print_object(sources):
    for url in sources:
        soup_object = bs(req.get(url).text, "html.parser")
        print(soup_object.get_text())


def main():
    login()
    print_object(sources)

main()
```

Comment: Is the first request working? ( by working I mean is it logging you in )

Comment: Yes it does successfully go through the first login page , and if i try to get a status.code, the first gives me a 200, while the second gives me a 404. both have the same action url in the html POST request. I have also tried adding the data from the first and second payload together into one (due to them being to the same url) and did not manage to log in at all that way.

Comment: The fact that you are receiving a status code of `200` doesn't mean much when it comes to logging in as it just tells you that the request was received and understood and is being processed. It doesn't really tell you if you have logged successfully or not try using printing the HTML content of your request (using `.text`) then you will have an idea if you are really logged in or not. keep me updated on what you see.

Comment: Yea if you look at the print_object function, I was also using that function to check the html every step of the way. in order to get to the second page with the security question you have to log into the first page successfully, which is where im ending up everytime. I only checked the status code to see if they both pulled a 200, which would tell me the issue was with maybe my credentials or something in my code (the credentials are correct of course I can log in in my browser). But i did end up gettin a 404 on the second request

Comment: Well that's great then, give me sec I will try and write an answer

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Comment: If needed I can send you my actual credentials for the webpage, nothing on there im really worried about

Comment: Well if my answer doesn't work that sure would help :)

Comment: now give me a sec I will look around and see what I can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Part 1

After looking around the website, that a bad part of the problem relies on the `payload2` you just have to add another item to it which is: `"formName":"loginChallengeValidation"` so overall `payload2`should look something like this:

```
payload2 = {"formName":"loginChallengeValidation","securityAnswer": your_security_answer,
            "Request": "postForm"}
```

This will prevent you from getting the status code `404`. Hope this helps.

---

### Part 2

Even though this the issue in your questions I doubt that this is what you really want (as the code in Part 1 will redirect you to another verification form). in order to get access to the website itself you would have to add the following lines:

```
header2 = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:60.0)      Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0", "Referer":"https://www.dandh.com/v4/view?pageReq=LoginChallengeValidation"}
```

and

```
req.post("https://www.dandh.com/v4/view?pageReq=LoginChallengeValidation", headers=header)
```

so your final code should look like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import time
sources = ["https://www.dandh.com/v4/view?pageReq=dhMainNS"]
req = requests.Session()


def login():
    authentication_url = "https://www.dandh.com/v4/dh"

    header = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:60.0)      Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"}
    header2 = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:60.0)      Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0", "Referer":"https://www.dandh.com/v4/view?pageReq=LoginChallengeValidation"}

    payload = {"Login": your_username,
           "PW": your_pasword,
           "Request": "Login"}

    payload2 = {"formName":"loginChallengeValidation","securityAnswer": your_security_answer,
            "Request": "postForm", "btContinue": ""}

    req.post(authentication_url, data=payload, headers=header)
    req.post("https://www.dandh.com/v4/view?pageReq=LoginChallengeValidation", headers=header)
    
    time.sleep(3)

    req.post(authentication_url, data=payload2, headers=header2)
    
    time.sleep(3)


def print_object(sources):
    for url in sources:
        soup_object = bs(req.get(url).text, "html.parser")
        print(soup_object.get_text())


def main():
    login()
    print_object(sources)

main()
```

(PS: you should replace `your_username`, `your_password` and `your_security_answer` with your credentials)
Also, I would like to note that I don't think that `time.sleep(3)` is useful in the code.

Really hope this helps.

Comment: You are awesome sir!!! appreciate the help very much!! I have to ask, why did the separate headers file need to be created? if ti held the same data?

Comment: You're very welcome if this answer solved your problem could you please click on the grey tick (near the upvote and downvote buttons of my answer)

Comment: also if there is any other issues feel free to ask :)

Comment: I edited my comment with a question about the headers variable, and im trying to upvote the answer but as im new it says I dont have enough reputation

Comment: No need to upvote (though thanks for the effort) the green tick just shows everyone that the problem was solved :)